# Web app architecture for third party API calls

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm building a simple search engine that takes a user submitted search query as input and outputs a list of appropriate search results.  Search queries ultimately get sent to a third party API, which does the heavy lifting of generating search results.

There are 2 ways I can handle this workflow:

1. My server takes user requests, queries the third party API, and returns results to the user

   *or*
2. Shifting this responsibility to the client-side; the client queries the third party API directly.

What are some considerations when choosing between these 2 methods?

Comment: It is not really possible to answer this question. It is too broad. It asks a general opinion without specifying any details about the specific task. So how to you expect to get an answer that really makes sense?

Comment: [**Here**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/138565) is an answer you could take into account. It comes down to how much API logic you are willing to expose to the outside world, and where you think it will run the fastest/in the most efficient way.

Comment: Personally, I would use option #1.  This gives you the most flexibility down the road in the case of changes to the third-party API.  And, I would always prefer to implement any business logic/transformation server-side - who knows, you might even end up with other UIs that need to perform the same searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using option #1 gives you a few advantages like:

- You have one API for one view. It brings some clarity in your architecture.
- You might have a lot of pages/windows/whatever using same search API. If third-party API changes or moves to another domain or does something which makes you change your code, you can fix only one API method on your server instead of fixing all your clients.
- You can perform some additional changes with your search query like translating it if third-party search engine can't do it itself. Formally, you can implement some additional logic.

Using option #2 reduces the burden on your server.

Comment: By the way, if you are really hesitating, you can perform a trick: from your client-side call your server's API, but from server's API just redirect client's request to the third-party API.
This will reduce the burden on your server and give you an ability to change your choice without changing client's code.